# Getter in class is always undefined

Tags: typescript, undefined, getter

I have a typescript class which contains a getter (which is just a concatenation of multiple properties).

For some reason, the getter always returns undefined, even if the properties inside are all defined.

```
import { IdDisplayName } from './';

export class Person {
  id?: number;
  age!: number;
  personType!: IdDisplayName<number>;
  name!: string = '';

  public get description() : string {
    return this.name + ' • ' + (this.personType.displayName ?? 'No type')
      + '/' + this.age;
  }
}
```

I'm receiving the data as a Json and casting to Person like so:

```
let person = result as Person;
let desc = person.description; //undefined, never enters the description getter code.
```

Comment: Casting does not instantiate a class, it merely tells the typescript compiler that `result` should be treated like a `Person` class... which it isn't.

Comment: Oh ok. In this case, what would be the solution to the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting does not instantiate a class, it merely tells the compiler to treat your `result` like a `Person` class... which probably isn't the case yet.

You have to do what you probably expected the cast to do by itself, create a `constructor` inside your `Person` class and instantiate a instance of `Person` with the `new` key-word.

```
export class Person {
  constructor(res: any){
    // assign properties
  }
}

var desc = new Person(result).description;
```

Comment: I did that, I just set the parameter as optional with a return, in case I need to instantiate without having any data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are casting result as person instead of instantiating a new instance of person. Here is a potential fix -

```
import { IdDisplayName } from './';

export class Person {
  constructor(result: 'your result type here') {
    this.id = result.id;
    this.age = result.age;
    this.personType = result.personType;
    this.name = result.name;
  }
  id?: number;
  age!: number;
  personType!: IdDisplayName<number>;
  name = '';

  public get description(): string {
    return (
      this.name +
      ' • ' +
      (this.personType.displayName ?? 'No type') +
      '/' +
      this.age
    );
  }
}
```

then it can be used like this -

```
let person = new Person(result)
```